# IF syntax error in PostgreSQL procedure using sql language

Tags: postgresql

**I am writing PostgreSQL procedure like below**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.reply_proc(IN reply_by bigint, IN id bigint, IN reply character varying,IN reply_to bigint, IN status integer ,IN is_forward boolean DEFAULT false)
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    
AS $BODY$ 
INSERT INTO replied(reply_by,id,created_date,status,is_forward,reply_to) VALUES(reply_by,id,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),status,is_forward,reply_to);

IF(status != 0) 
THEN
    UPDATE table2 SET status = 2,updated_on = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)  WHERE id = id;
END 

IF(is_forward == false)
UPDATE table3 SET status = 4,updated_on = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) WHERE id = citizen_app_id;

$BODY$;
```

I am getting Error at IF 'Invalid Syntax' I am new to PostgreSQL. How we can do this?

Comment: @Alex Even this test procedure gives invalid If `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test(IN num integer)
    LANGUAGE 'sql' 
AS $BODY$
IF num = 2 THEN
  select * from table1;
END IF

$BODY$;`

Comment: you need [`language plpgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) - SQL has not IF. And the "equals" operator in SQL **and** PL/pgSQL is `=` not `==`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test(IN num integer)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
IF num = 2 THEN
  select * from table1;
END IF

$BODY$;` If Syntax error

Comment: Did you even bother to read the [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) reference?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I am writing according to the ` PL/pgSQL` Conditionals. Even then I am getting Syntax error.

Comment: You missed the [structure of PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)

Comment: @Alex: Version 9.1 is EOL since october 2016, please use the "current" documentation or the version mentioned in a topic. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Unrelated, but you should make sure your function partners don't have the same name as the columns you are referencing in your table.  It is common to use a prefix like _ or p_ to clearly differentiate the parameters.